# Div overlay over several table columns

Tags: html, css

I have a table over which I am trying to overlay a div per row, from the beginning of the cell of the second column to the end of the cell of the last column.

I can change the width of the overlay to a given value like, let's say, 200px; but I would ideally like to specify the value of that width so that the div perfectly "anchors" to the end of the cell.

HTML code:

```
<table style="width:200px; background:#eee;">
<tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class="event-container">C
        <div class="event" style="background:red; width: 100%;">XXX-XXX</div>
    </td>
    <td>D</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class="event-container">E
        <div class="event" style="background:blue; width: 200px;">XXX-XXX</div>
    </td>
    <td>F</td>
</tr>
```

CSS code:

```
tr { height: 25px; }
.event-container { position: relative; }
.event { position: absolute; }
.event { top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 1000; }
.event { height: 100%; opacity: 0.25 }
```

Take a look at the following fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/rtubio/sohwqmzs/3/

Is there any way in which to tell HTML "span the div to the end of the cell X" with CSS without using JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, I have used jQuery for this

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    jQuery(".event-container").each(function(){
   var w=jQuery(this).width();
   jQuery(this).children("div.event").css("width", w);
 });
});
```

```css
.event-container { position: relative; }
.event { position: absolute; }
.event { top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 1000; }
.event { height: 100%; opacity: 0.25 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:200px; background:#eee;">
<tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class="event-container">C
        <div class="event" style="background:red; width: 100%;">XXX-XXX</div>
    </td>
    <td>D</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class="event-container">E
        <div class="event" style="background:blue; width: 200px;">XXX-XXX</div>
    </td>
    <td>F</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This solution spans the overlaying div exactly to the end of the tag "E", but I would like the overlay to float over the "F" cell exactly to the end of the cell itself. Maybe by changing: "jQuery(this).children("div.event").css("width", 2*w);" ... so that the width is @doubled?

Comment: Yes, check the first answer given by me... it works but you have to wrap first the row of the table so that you can add a position:absolute div over the wrapping one. Check the attached fiddle.

Comment: This is the fiddle that I was working on: https://jsfiddle.net/rtubio/sohwqmzs/4/

Comment: As you can see, you can wrap it all pretty well by using this technique and it does not require of JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the demo below these lines.

I have changed the div to span tag in your  and also changed the CSS position of event class to relative.

This might solve your problem.

```css
tr {
  height: 25px;
}
.event-container {
  position: relative;
}
.event {
  position: relative;
}
.event {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.event {
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.25
}
```

```html
<table style="width:200px;background:#eee;">
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class="event-container">C
      <span class="event" style="background:red;">XXX-XXX</span>
    </td>
    <td>D</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td class="event-container">E
      <span class="event" style="background:blue;">XXX-XXX</span>
    </td>
    <td>F</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I have change the div to span in <td> and change CSS position for class event

Comment: Edit the post with your explanation.

Comment: This does not solve the problem since the overlaying div does not wrap cells "E" and "F" at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the following solution without using JavaScript at all. The solution passes by creating a sub-table within the row that I want to wrap, contained within a div element. This "div" element will be the container of the table and I can position another "div" overlaying the first one.

HTML code:

```
<table style="width:200px;background:#eee;">
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <div class="row-container">
                <table class="row-table">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="background: green;"></td>
                        <td style="background: orange;"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td class="event-container">C
            <div class="event" style="background:red; width: 100%;">XXX-XXX</div>
        </td>
        <td>D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td class="event-container">E
            <div class="event" style="background:blue; width: 150px;">XXX-XXX</div>
        </td>
        <td>F</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <div class="row-container">
                <table class="row-table">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="background: green;"></td>
                        <td style="background: orange;"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="row-overlay"></div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS Code:

```
tr {
    height: 25px;
}
.event-container {
    position: relative;
}
.event {
    position: absolute;
}
.event {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.event {
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.25
}

.row-container {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black
}

.row-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.50;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.row-table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

You can check it all out in the following fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rtubio/sohwqmzs/4/